# Symfony2, Doctrine, fixtures, Array to string conversion

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I am working with my database already a month. Suddenly i started to get the error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
 Notice: Array to string conversion
```

, when loading fixtures. Finally, i deleted all database, rerun migrations, left only 1 fixtures file (thus i commented our OrderedFIxturesInterface, and of course i cleared the cache, but the error remains).
 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2_27\src\MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUsers01.php

```
<?php

namespace MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use MeetingBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface; 

class LoadUsers01 extends AbstractFixture 
#implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            $fuser = new User();
            $fuser->setUsername('name'.$i);
            $fuser->setEmail('g.statkute'.$i.'@gmail.com');
            $fuser->setIsActive(True); // i also used 1
            $fuser->setPassword('pswd'.$i);
            $manager->persist($fuser);
           # $this->addReference('fuser:name'.$i, $fuser);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

        public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

.

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2_27\src\MeetingBundle\Entity\User.php

```
..
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tuser")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
..
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", nullable=true, unique=true)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $password;

..

 /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }
   /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $isActive
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }
```

Table contains varchar fields except of tinyint for boolean IsActive. There is only one tabel with name users.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tuser`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tuser` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `roles` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `gravatar` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `webpages` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json_array)',
  `createdAtInt` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loggedInInt` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loggedOutInt` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tuser`
--
ALTER TABLE `tuser`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_66A7B847F85E0677` (`username`);
```

THE VERBOSE ERROR:

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27>php app/console doctrine:fixture
s:load -vv
[2015-12-18 05:45:10] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".

[2015-12-18 05:45:10] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener
"Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand".
[2015-12-18 05:45:10] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener
"Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand".
Careful, database will be purged. Do you want to continue y/N ?y
  > purging database
  > loading [1] MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUsers01



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Notice: Array to string conversion



Exception trace:
 () at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:67
 Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError() at n/a:n/a
 PDOStatement->bindValue() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\ve
ndor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:67
 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement->bindValue() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0
\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php:120
 Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->bindValue() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\
proj3_27\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersi
ster.php:277
 Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister->executeInserts() at C:\Bit
nami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\U
nitOfWork.php:1018
 Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->executeInserts() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_
prog\proj3_27\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php:378
 Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\pro
j3_27\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php:356
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\p
roj3_27\src\MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUsers01.php:32
 MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUsers01->load() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.
30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\doctrine\data-fixtures\lib\Doctrine\Common\DataFix
tures\Executor\AbstractExecutor.php:121
 Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\AbstractExecutor->load() at C:\Bitnami\wa
mpstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\doctrine\data-fixtures\lib\Doctrine\Co
mmon\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor.php:83
 Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor->Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures
\Executor\{closure}() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\doct
rine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php:233
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->transactional() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sy
m_prog\proj3_27\vendor\doctrine\data-fixtures\lib\Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\E
xecutor\ORMExecutor.php:85
 Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor->execute() at C:\Bitnami\wamp
stack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-fixtures-bundle\Comman
d\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php:118
 Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Command\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand->execute
() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\symfony\symfony\src
\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30
-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Applic
ation.php:846
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5
.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\A
pplication.php:189
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0
\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Con
sole\Application.php:96
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\Bitnami\wamps
tack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Con
sole\Application.php:120
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\s
ym_prog\proj3_27\app\console:27
```

Comment: Out of 25 questions you have yet to accept a single answer.  Strange.

Comment: I have deleted once more all database and all migrations - maybe the reason was that i had old migrations. Regenerated everything from zero giving custom names for the tables. Cleared cache. But than i try to load Users fixtures i am getting the error: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: When i updated composer.

Comment: And finally i have created a new project, new database, new bundle, copied entities, rerun migrations. But than i try to run fixtures i am getting the same error: ing custom names for the tables. Cleared cache. But than i try to load Users fixtures i am getting the error: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException] Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: You may have missed the point of my comment.  So far you have posted literally dozens of questions.  None of which have been answered to your satisfaction.  Why would you think that anyone would spend time trying to answer this one?  The problem of course is that webpages array cannot be null but there is really no point in telling you that.

Comment: As far as i noticed, i am answering my own questions by myself. I can not give points for myself, despite all my satisfaction than i resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with roles field, which i changed yesterday evening to the string instead of array. But i forget to remove initialization $roles = array();

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $roles; // it was $roles= array();
```

Thus if you see this error, search for keyword "array" in related files and check if assign variable is supposed to be equal to array, etc..

This is the fourth time when i have redone all project because of simple error. The conclusion is that better it to keep thinking where can be a mistake. On the other hand, when doctrine was not generating crud, reinstalling the project with different Symfony version helped.
    private $roles; // = array();